# Why are some webpages all rendering using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I just begin to learn web design. And I want to learn some design style and I noticed that most web pages are part static html and part javasript. But why some web pages are all rendering using javascript? Is it for safe reason or for saving traffic load ? I know using javascript can save the traffic load but I don't know what's the point all using javascript.

Comment: Beware that search engine indexing will ignore javascript, thus dynamically generated content. your website will not be correctly indexed if you don't provide enough static information. In this case, you ought to use meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static page, then it's usually not a great use case for all javascript. But if it has dynamic data or interactivity it can be easier to use javascript to create the views as it's rendered rather than rendering it all, and then using javascript to query the elements to make changes or interactivity